# Applet não executa no browser

Tags: java, html

Não executa o Applet. Só da esse retorno.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é minha classe java.

```
public class SiteSelector extends JApplet {

private HashMap<String, URL> sites; // nomes e URLs de site
private ArrayList<String> siteNames; // nomes de sites
private JList siteChooser; // lista do sites a escolher

//le os parametros e configura a GUI
public void init(){
    sites = new HashMap<String,URL>();
    siteNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    //otem os parametros do documento XHTML
    getSitesFormHTMLParmeters();

    //cria componentes GUI e a interface layout
    add( new JLabel("Choose a stie to browser"), BorderLayout.NORTH);

    siteChooser = new JList(siteNames.toArray()); // preenche a JList
    siteChooser.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        //vai ao site selecionado pelo usuário
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //obtem o nome do site selecionado
            Object object = siteChooser.getSelectedValue();

            //utiliza o nome do site para localizar a URL correspondente
            URL newDocument = sites.get(object);

            //obtem o conteiner de applets 
            AppletContext browser = getAppletContext();

            //instrui o conteiner de applets a mudar as paginas
            browser.showDocument(newDocument);
        }
    }); // classe interna anonima

    add(new JScrollPane(siteChooser),BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

//obetem os paramentros do documento XHTML
private void getSitesFormHTMLParmeters(){
    String title; // titutlo do site
    String location = ""; // localização do site
    URL url; // URL da localização
    int counter = 0; // conta o nuemro de sites

    title = getParameter("title" + counter); // obtem o primeiro titulo do site

    //faz um loop até que não haja mais parametros no documento XHTML
    while(title != null){
        //obtem a localização do site
        location = getParameter("location" + location);

        try{//coloca titulo/URL no HashMap e titulo na ArrayList
            url = new URL(location); // converte a localização em URL
            sites.put(title,url); // coloca titulo/URL no HashMap
            siteNames.add(title); // coloca o titulo no ArrayList
        }catch(MalformedURLException urlException){
            urlException.printStackTrace();
        }
        ++counter;
        title = getParameter("title" + counter); // obtem o proximo titulo do site
    }
}
```

}

Esta é a minha HTML.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que estou fazendo de errado?
O arquivo html coloquei no diretorio /bin jundo com .class

Comment: Como você está abrindo esse arquivo HTML? Você está usando algum servidor local? Simplesmente abrindo o arquivo HTML no browser? Sua janela me lembra muito o appletrunner (ou apppletviewer, não sei - faz anos que não mexo com Applets), você estaria por acaso usando um comando assim pra tentar abrir seu applet?

Comment: Estou abrindo no browser de forma normal.

Comment: Tipo, `file:///caminho/pro/arquivo.html`?

Comment: Isso mesmo. E é um exemplo de um livro de java do Deitel.

Comment: Por mais que eu procure, não encontro a informação se pode ou não executar um applet no sistema de arquivos local, sem servidor... Vou deixar que alguém com experiência recente em Java responda, então, infelizmente não me lembro mesmo desse detalhe.

Comment: Tranquilo mgibsonbr. Agradeço pela atenção.

Comment: O browser chega a lhe fazer as perguntas de permissão de execução para este applet?

Comment: Chega sim. Dou a permissão. E não executa o applet. Já baixei de segurança e mesmo assim não consigo executar.

Comment: Tenta colocar nas configurações do java o caminho para o arquivo como site seguro ou permitido de execução de applets

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 3):

Assumindo que ainda não deste com o problema, noto que no teu HTML tens alguns erros que causam uma visualização incorreta ou nula do teu Applet.

#### Tag `applet`

Onde defines a altura, tens um erro de escrita em que `heiht` deveria ser `height`:

```html
<applet codebase="." code="solo.SiteSelector.class" width="300" heiht="75">
  <!-- ... -->
</applet>
```

Deveria ser:

```html
<applet codebase="." code="solo.SiteSelector.class" width="300" height="75">
  <!-- ... -->
</applet>
```

Isto pode dar origem a que o teu `applet` fique com altura igual a zero, onde apesar de estar em execução, acabas por não o visualizar.

**Nota:**
Como pode ser visto na [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/using_tags.html) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>, trata-se de uma atributo obrigatório, o que por si só, o erro de digitação é suficiente para justificar o teu problema.

#### Atributo `code`

No teu atributo `code` na tag `applet` tens escrito:

```
code="solo.SiteSelector.class"
```

Mas como não sei de onde vem o `solo`, a julgar pelo código na tua pergunta deverias ter apenas:

```
code="SiteSelector.class"
```

Pode ver na [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> que o atributo `code` é suposto conter o nome da classe, e a tua classe chama-se `SiteSelector`.

**Nota:**
Por outro lado, podes também passar `packagename.classname.class`, ou seja, `meuPacote.minhaClasse.class` conforme pode ser visto na [documentação nesta página](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/using_tags.html) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>.
No teu caso será pacote `solo` e a classe `SiteSelector` se for essa a realidade.

#### Atributo `codebase`

O atributo `codebase` serve para indicar o caminho para para os ficheiros. O mesmo é utilizado em conjunção com o valor do atributo `code`.

No teu caso estás a indicar que o ficheiro está em:

```
./solo.SiteSelector.class
```

O `.` seguido do `solo.SiteSelector.class` deveria dar um caminho válido, confirma se é o teu caso.

#### Tag `param`

Na tua segunda tag `<param/>` tens o atributo que contém o valor com o nome mal escrito:

```html
<param name="location0" valeu="http://java.sun.com/">
```

Deveria ser:

```html
<param name="location0" value="http://java.sun.com/">
```

---

Após resolução do em cima indicado poderás ter o problema resolvido ou poderás ter ultrapassado parte do problema.

Ficam umas ideias para melhor explorar a situação caso tenhas apenas ultrapassado parte do problema:

1. Alterar a cor de fundo da tab `<body/>` para saberes se o Applet está ou não a ser executado, pois o fundo deverá ficar verde e o teu Applet terá um fundo de cor diferente, provavelmente branco:

   ```
   <body bgcolor="green">
   ```
2. Normalmente os navegadores são 32Bit, mas já tens versões 64Bit disponíveis, verifica se estás a usar a versão de Java 32 bit ou 64Bit e cruza a informação com o navegador para saberes se ambos partilham a mesma arquitetura.
3. Experimenta o teu Applet com o [appletviewer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/appletviewer.html) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> que podes executar a partir do terminal:

   ```
   appletviewer meuFicheiro.html
   ```